# NSLog a NSCFString's class, but the result is sth else,like UIView ,UIButton... and then crashed

Tags: ios

In a singleton object, I add object into one of its properties(NSMutableArray _service),

like this:
     [_service addObject:[[Entity alloc] initWithID:nid type:type title:title titleImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",preurl,titleImage] ]];

And then I traversed the singleton object's _service in another object, NSLog its property's(titleImage) class, 
like this:
     NSLog(@"%@",((Entity*)[_sharedData.service objectAtIndex:i]).titleImage.class);
sometimes the result is all NSCFStrings,it's correct.But sometimes it became UIButton or UIView and so on, then the app crashed.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

That happens because at some point during program execution you lose reference to your object. i.e your object gets released. Or somehow if your object is depending on some other object that got released leaving an invalid reference for your object. 
Please check if you are using release/retain/copy properly.

Comment: Thanks very much. I solved it.
I think that many problem like this is always caused by its own reference!